Publishing MAUI App - The newly created provisioning profile is not listed, but the old ones are
I am trying to publish my MAUI app, but the newly created provisioning profile is not showing up, although the old ones that are about to expire are listed. I have Xcode 16, Visual Studio 2022, and Visual Studio Code installed.
I followed the process of 'Request a certificate from a certificate authority' from Keychain Access, then created the distribution certificate, identifier, provisioning profile, and created the app in App Store Connect.
Then, from Xcode, I linked my account and performed the "download manual profiles" process.
I created a MAUI project in Visual Studio 2022 and another one in Visual Studio Code using the '.NET MAUI - Archive / Publish tool' extension, and added 'ApplicationTitle', 'ApplicationId', and 'ApplicationGuid' in the .csproj file.
Then, from Visual Studio 2022, in the properties under iOS, Bundle Signing, I tried adding the 'Signing Identity', but the created provisioning profile does not show up in the Provisioning Profile section.
Here is an image of the error I'm experiencing:

What other way is there now to generate the Bundled and send it to Testflight?


Looks like this is a tooling issue with the .NET MAUI VS Code Extension, you can go to the NET MAUI VS Code Extension repository to report it. 2. You can also Publish an iOS app using the command line, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-8.0.

